# How to put return value into another return value in JS vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, return-value

I want the "topic1"  to be the value of my breed name and key, but when I try to put this.topic1 to replace the manual typing, it shows nothing.

Or there are any other method to have my button name same as my retrieve API param, and sent it name when I click it?

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  components: { Async },

  data() {
    return {
      topic1: null,
      topic2: null,

      currentBreed: 0,
      breeds: [
        { name: this.topic1 , key: this.topic1 },
        { name: "German Shepherd", key: "germanshepherd" },
        { name: "Husky", key: "husky" },
        { name: "Pug", key: "pug" },
        { name: "(Error)", key: "error" },
      ]
    }
  },
  async created() {
    try {
      this.promise = axios.get(
        "https://k67r3w45c4.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/TwitterTrends"
      );
      const res = await this.promise;
      this.topic1 = res.data[0].Trends;
      this.topic2 = res.data[1].Trends;  
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }  
  },

  async mounted () {

  let test = this.topic1;


  },
  computed: {

    breedKey() {
      return this.breeds[this.currentBreed].key;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but if you want `breeds` to include an entry based on `topic1` it should probably be a `computed` property instead of `data`. Either that or set the relevant properties of `breeds[0]` once the request completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

The `data` function is called just once, when the corresponding Vue instance is created. Within that function you can get a reference to its Vue instance via `this`. At that point some properties, such as those corresponding to `props`, will already exist. However, others won't.

The object returned from `data` is used to create new properties on the instance. In this case you're creating 4 properties: `topic1`, `topic2`, `currentBreed` and `breeds`. Vue creates those properties based on that returned object, so they won't exist until after the `data` function is run.

So when you write `{ name: this.topic1 , key: this.topic1 },` within that `data` function you're attempting to access a property called `topic1` that doesn't exist yet. As such it will have a value of `undefined`. So you're creating an entry equivalent to `{ name: undefined , key: undefined },`.

Further, there is no link back to `topic1`. That object won't be updated when the value of `topic1` changes.

It's also worth noting a few points about timing.

1. The `data` function will be called before the `created` hook, so the `axios` call isn't made until after the `data` properties are populated.
2. An `axios` call is asynchronous.
3. Using `await` may make the code a little easier to read but the 'waiting' is mostly just an illusion. The remaining code inside the function won't run until the awaited promise is resolved but that won't cause anything outside of the function to wait. `await` is equivalent to using `then`.
4. The component will render just after the `created` hook is called. This is synchronous, it won't wait for the `axios` request. The `mounted` hook will then be called, all before the `axios` call has completed.

All of this means you may need to adjust your template to handle the case where the `axios` call hasn't completed yet as it will initially render prior to the values of `topic1` and `topic2` being available.

Specifically addressing the `breeds` property you have a few options. One is to inject the values in once the value has loaded:

```js
breeds: [
  { name: "" , key: "" }, // Initially empty values
  { name: "German Shepherd", key: "germanshepherd" },
  // ...
```

```js
const res = await this.promise;
this.topic1 = res.data[0].Trends;
this.topic2 = res.data[1].Trends;  
this.breeds[0].name = this.breeds[0].key = this.topic1;
```

Another is to use a `computed` property for `breeds` (you'd remove it from the `data` for this):

```js
computed: {
  breeds () {
    return [
      { name: this.topic1 , key: this.topic1 },
      { name: "German Shepherd", key: "germanshepherd" },
      { name: "Husky", key: "husky" },
      { name: "Pug", key: "pug" },
      { name: "(Error)", key: "error" },
    ]
  }
}
```

As we're using a `computed` property it will be updated when `topic1` changes as it's a reactive dependency.

Using a `computed` property is probably the most natural solution in this case but there are other tricks you can use to get this to work.

For example, you could use property getters for the two properties in that first breed object (that's JavaScript property getters, nothing to do with Vue):

```js
data () {
  const vm = this;

  return {
    topic1: null,
    topic2: null,

    currentBreed: 0,
    breeds: [
      {
        get name () {
          return vm.topic1;
        },

        get key () {
          return vm.topic1;
        }
      },
      { name: "German Shepherd", key: "germanshepherd" },
      { name: "Husky", key: "husky" },
      { name: "Pug", key: "pug" },
      { name: "(Error)", key: "error" },
    ]
  }
},
```

I'm not advocating this approach for your use case but it is an interesting way to do it that can sometimes be useful. The key thing to note is how the dependency on `topic1` is evaluated only when the properties `name` and `key` are accessed, not when the `data` function is executed. This allows `topic1` to be registered as a dependency of whatever is accessing `name` and `key`, e.g. during rendering.

Comment: Thank you so much, it work totally fine, I can guess the value is still null, but dont know the way to inject it. Thanks again